# Looking for centrally managed full-disk encryption product for Windows 7

Tags: windows, encryption, disk-encryption

Let me start this off by saying I've already evaluated and have planned to purchase SecureDoc Enterprise from WinMagic. However, due to billing issues (not price) I'm afraid I may not be able to make that purchase so I'm now scrambling to find a replacement product. I've got 7 news laptops coming in about 1.5 weeks and I need to deploy full-disk encryption on them.

I'm looking for something with the following features:

- Allows user to locally reset forgotten encryption password without requiring a rescue disk and without requiring network connectivity. SecureDoc uses security questions or an administrator assisted one-time key.
- Allows user to bypass Windows login by passing domain credentials to pre-boot login.
- Centrally managed and policy based.

It should go without saying that the product should have good security/encryption practices and not require a week of training for the admin or user.

Thanks!

edit: I found out that I can purchase the software through Softchoice rather than having to go direct. It's a little unfortunate that the sales person at WinMagic didn't tell me I could go through a reseller even though he knew I had a billing issue. The issue is that they do not accept American Express and we felt their credit app form asked for too much information.

Comment: When you evaluated it, what did you compare it against and what came second?

Comment: It fit my needs and expectations well, came highly recommended from a trusted colleague, and has a decent price so I haven't evaluated anything else.

Answer (score 1):

PGP Full Disk Encryption may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

BitLocker is built into Windows 7. Using the Laptop's TPM you wouldn't need a password to unlock the disk, the user would login to Windows with their standard domain password. You can use GPO to store recovery keys in AD; recovering a locked disk would require an admin to get the key from AD (though this should not be a problem anyway). It's what we use internally.